# Proving a particular function is surjective on a Banach space.

Tags: banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(E,\|x\|)$ and let $f: E \to E$ such that $f+Id$ is a contraction ($Id$ is the identity map). Prove that $f$ is surjective and prove that, if $f$ is linear, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

The attempt at a solution:

I am having a hard time with this exercise. For the first part, I want to prove that given $y \in E$, there exists $x \in E$: $f(x)=y$. If I define the function $g(x)=f(x)+Id$, then $g$ must have a unique fixed point by the fixed point theorem. However, I don't know how to use this information to find the $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ for a given $y$.

For the second part, I am confused about the following: suppose I've proved $f$ is surjective, would this imply $f$ is injective? I know this is true for endomorphisms defined on a finite dimensional vector space, but $E$ could be of infinite dimension. So, how could I assure that $f^{-1}$ exists?. I also have problems to prove that $f$ is continuous.

I would appreciate if someone can help me (with hints, ideas or suggestions) to prove these things.

Comment: Use the geometric series.

Comment: For the first part, you want $f(x) = y$. How can you modify $g$ so that a) the modified function $h$ is still a contraction, and b) $x$ is a fixed point of $h$ if and only if $f(x) = y$?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it: given $y \in E$, I define $h_y(x)=g(x)-y$. Let $x,z \in E$, $d(h(x),h(z))=d(g(x)-y,g(z)-y)=d(g(x),g(z))<d(x,z)$. So $h$ is a contraction map on a Banach space, then $h$ has a unique fixed point, call it $x$, $h(x)=x \iff g(x)-y=x \iff f(x)+x-y=x \iff f(x)=y$, this proves $f$ is surjective. Reaaally useful, thanks!

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, thanks for the suggestion, but I still don't get how to use the geometric series, I need a tiny little push with that.

Comment: $f = -(I - (f+I))$.  Since $f+I$ is a contraction, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (f+I)^k$ is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

After the suggestions, I could solve some parts of the problem:

To prove $f$ is surjective, given $y \in E$, if one defines $h_y:E \to E : h(x)=g(x)-y$, then for $x,z \in E$, $d(h(x),h(z))=d(g(x)-y,g(z)-y)=d(g(x),g(z))<d(x,z)$, which means $h_y$ is a contraction on a complete metric space, then $h_y$ has a unique fixed point. Let $x$ be the fixed point of $h_y$, $h(x)=x \iff g(x)-y=x \iff f(x)+x-y=x \iff f(x)=y$, it follows that $f$ is surjective.

For the second part, suppose $f$ is linear. We have to prove that $f$ is continuous, bijective and that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. As $E$ is a Banach space, $f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f$ is bounded. 
$\|f(x)\|=\|f(x)+Id(x)-Id(x)\|\leq \|f(x)+Id(x)\|+\|Id(x)\|$

By hypothesis, $f+Id$ is a contraction $\implies$ $f+Id$ is continuous $\implies$ $f+Id$ is bounded. Then, for every $x \in E$, $\|f(x)\|\leq \|f(x)+Id(x)\|+\|Id(x)\|\leq c\|x\|+\|x\|=(c+1)\|x\|$, this proves $f$ is continuous.

With Stephen's comments I could prove injectivity of $f$ and continuity  of $f^{-1}$:

First lets prove that there exists $m>0 : m\|x\|\leq \|f(x)\|$:
$\|x\|=\|x+f(x)-f(x)\|\leq \|x+f(x)\|+\|f(x)\| \implies \|x\|-\|x+f(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|$. We know there exists $c>0:\|x+f(x)\|\leq c\|x\| \implies (1-c)\|x\|\leq \|x\|-\|x+f(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|$.

Suppose there are $a\neq b, a,b \in E: f(a)=f(b) \iff f(a)-f(b)=0 \iff f(a-b)=0$.

But $0<m\|a-b\|\leq \|f(a-b)\|=0$, which is absurd.

So there exist $m,M>0: m\|x\|\leq \|f(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$, with this, I can prove that $f^{-1}$ is bounded:
Let $y \in E$, then there is $x \in E: y=f(x) \implies m\|f^{-1}(y)\|=mf^{-1}(f(x))=m\|x\|\leq \|f(x)\|=\|y\|$. Then $\|f^{-1}(y)\|\leq \dfrac{1}{m}\|y\| \implies f^{-1}$ is continuous. It follows that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: $\|(I+f)x\| = \|x+f(x)\| \le c \|x\|$, where $0\le c<1$.  What does this say about a lower bound for $\|f(x)\|$?

Comment: Hmm, all I've managed to do was to show $\|f(x)+Id(x)\|-\|Id(x)\|\leq \|f(x)\|$, but then I would conclude $(c-1)\|x\|$, and this doesn't help me since $c-1<0$, I think that you are suggesting me to conclude something like $m\|x\|\leq \|f(x)\|\leq M\|x\|$ in order to prove continuity of $f^{-1}$, but I still don't see how to find $m$.

Comment: How about $\|f(x)\| \ge \|Id(x)\| - \|f(x) + Id(x)\|$?

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing all up, now I got it. I'll write it above, thanks very much!

Comment: Also, about my other hint: if $g$ is a linear contraction on a Banach space, then you can show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty g^k$ exists, and that it is a two sided inverse to $(I-g)$.  Multiply it out and see.

Comment: I'll think about this and ask if I have doubts, thanks again.

Comment: You also have proved injectivity.  Suppose $f(x) = 0$, and $x \ne 0$?  What have you just proved?

Comment: And remember $f$ is linear.  So to prove injectivity, you just need to show that $f(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$.

Comment: Oh aaall right, $0<m\|x\|\leq \|f(x)\|=0$, which is clearly absurd.